# Is there a way to get mat-icon by id and change the value of matBadge={{0}}

Tags: angular, typescript

```html
<mat-icon id="matId" matBadge={{0}} matBadgeColor="warn"></mat-icon>
```

Is there a way to get mat-icon by its id and change the value of  `matBadge={{0}}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I think you're going about it the wrong way. Instead of selecting it and then updating the innerText, use angulars data binding (because that's what it's for).

Declare a property in your component:

```
public badgeCount: number;
```

In your MatIcon, change your code so it's:

```
matBadge="{{badgeCount}}"
```

or

```
[matBadge]="badgeCount"
```

Then in your component code, wherever you're wanting to update the badge number, just do this:

`this.badgeCount = 1;`

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Ya that would work but the problem I am facing if I do that all of the user get the same notification. I am working on private messaging app

Comment: I think your problem is with the tool you're using to push the notifications. Only one user can be accessing your app at the same time. So, if you're using something like SocketIO or SignalR (assuming that's the case), you need to look into how you send private messages or target specific sockets. The statement still holds up that your approach to selecting the mat icon to updates it's data is not a good design and will inevitably lead to bigger issues.